# how to retrieve a new data from database in ascending order after one data is deleted?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have contact names which are arranged in ascending order with their name.

But when I delete one *contact name*, I want to retrieve the next to the deleted one in **ascending** order.

But I cannot make it right. Right now I'm retrieving with id but its not effective.

```
    function deleteContact($id)
    {
            $data = Contact::where('id', '>', $id)->first();

            $contact = Contact::find($id);
            $contact->delete();

            return $data;

        }
```

Comment: Have you checked our answers?

Comment: its not fetching data.

Comment: Please Tell us what is the error or difficulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use **orderBy** while querying Contacts not by `$data = Contact::where('id', '>', $id)->first();`,

```
function deleteContact($id)
{
    $contact = Contact::find($id);
    $contact->delete();

    $data = Contact::orderBy('name','asc')->first();
    return $data;
}
```

The orderBy method allows you to sort the result of the query by a given column(here you have to give 'name' column.)

For more details check this [Ordering, Grouping, Limit, & Offset](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#selects)

Try this and comment if you have any query.

Comment: it doesnt work. It not fetching the data from the db. –

Comment: @rakeshshrestha what is the column name of your contact name?

Comment: Oh so sorry!! .. since most of the answers were game I used get() which got me a json of all the database rows. since, I only needed one row from the top yours is correct. :D

Comment: Yeah. it's a Great :)

Answer (score 2):

if you want to show order By id

```
function deleteContact($id)
{
  $contact = Contact::find($id);
  $contact->delete();

  $data = Contact::orderBy('id','asc')->get();
  return $data;
}
```

if you want to show order by created date from last to first

```
function deleteContact($id)
{
  $contact = Contact::find($id);
  $contact->delete();

  $data = Contact::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->get();
  return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Order By

Eloquent

```
$data = Contact::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get();
```

query builder

```
$data = DB::table('contact')->orderBy('name','ASC')->get();
```

Comment: it doesnt work. It not fetching the data from the db.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function deleteContact($id)
{


        $contact = Contact::find($id);
        $contact->delete();

        $data = Contact::orderBy('name','asc')->first();
        return $data;

    }
```

Comment: it doesnt work. It not fetching the data from the db. –

Answer (score 0):

try this. First delete then retrieve data in ascending order.

```
function deleteContact($id){  
    Contact::where('id', '=', $id)->delete();
    $data = Contact::select('*')->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
    return $data; }
```